# WPF c# app.xaml accidentally deleted

Tags: wpf, app.xaml

I am working on a wpf application and for a reason i did remove App.Xaml and add app.cs witch contain main method.
and the application is working very well, but i need to add a resource dictionary and i did found that it will be add in App.Xaml in order to use it in all project window,
but now i don't have App.Xaml, i did Add one manually but it was not working it is not like the generated one .
any one can help me to add one without creating new project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you set the `Build Action` of the new added file to `ApplicationDefinition` in the properties window.

Comment: Where i can find it ? , That will create a new App.Xaml for me?

Comment: Each file has properties and there is a combobox with options for "Build Action". The new file your created, press F4 for options on it and change the combobox to say "ApplicationDefinition".

Comment: why don't you create a new dummy WPF application project and copy App.xaml in your main project, change the code behind class name then set the xaml file property as suggested.

Comment: Did so , now I got 2 errors:
Error 1 Markup file is not valid. Specify a source markup file with an .xaml extension.
Error 2 'Data at the root level is invalid.

Comment: I tried to add from a dummy project but its kinda made me some troubles because the App.Xaml dont know the App.cs .